# JQuery Autocomplete with source pointing to .aspx

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete

No matter how I return the data, as a List or as JSON string, the jQuery Autocomplete plugin does not show the values in the dropdown list.

Javascript:

```
$("#myText").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Default.aspx/GetList",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            data: "{'term':'" + request.term + "'}",
            success: function (data) {
                response(data);
            },
            error: function (xhr, error) {
                console.debug(xhr); console.debug(error);
            }
        });
    },
    minLength: 0,
    select: function (event, ui) {
        var result = ui.item.id;
    }
});
```

Server Side (.aspx):

```
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json), WebMethod]
public static string GetList(string term)
{
    List<string> list = new List<string>();
    list.Add("apple");
    list.Add("apricot");
    list.Add("apple cider");

    string json = "[" + string.Join(",",
    list.Select(i =>
        "{ 'id': '" + i + "'" + "}"
    )) + "]";

    return json;
}
```

I have attached 2 pictures, the first shows how it is displayed in the browser, the second one is a breakpoint in javascript.

What am I doing wrong?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

used JavaScriptSerializer, and it worked.

```
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json), WebMethod]
public static string GetList(string term)
{
    List<string> list = new List<string>();
    list.Add("apple");
    list.Add("apricot");
    list.Add("apple cider");

    JavaScriptSerializer serialize = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    string result = serialize.Serialize(list);
    return result;
}
```